# Date filter for GCP

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a date column with past, present & future dates. I want to exclude all past dates, how can I do this in GCP ?

I tried using below -

Select*
from Table
where Date > Current_Date()
However I get an error

Please help.

Comment: What error message do you see ? and  what type `Date` column is ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below query for your requirement:

```
WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT DATE '2022-11-10' AS Sample_Date union all
  SELECT DATE '2023-01-24' AS Sample_Date union all
  SELECT DATE '2023-01-25'AS Sample_Date

)

Select * from sample_data  where Sample_Date >= Current_Date();
```

**Result**

[image]
If this query does not satisfy your requirements, can you share the error message you are facing, sample input and sample output?